# jQuery filter :contains for a link (a href="#")

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a link that is currently:

```
a href="#"
```

but soon the client will change the link to

```
a href="something"
```

When the link becomes something I would like to use jQuery to change the css, but I am not sure how to write a filter for an attribute (href="")...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a selector for an anchor with an href not equal to hash:

```
$('a[href!="#"]')
```

Comment: +1. I missed the point that OP wants to do a negative search.

Comment: NP, we all do that sometimes :)

Answer (score 25):

Here are two options that you can use to compare your `href` attribute:

**Href is empty:**

```
$('a[href=""]') or $('a[href="#"]')
```

**Href isn't empty:**

```
$('a[href!=""]') or $('a[href!="#"]')
```

When comparing attributes, jQuery offers several operators for comparisions:

```
 = Is Equal
!= Is Not Equal
^= Starts With
$= Ends With
*= Contains
```

[More on jQuery Selectors here.](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)

Comment: +1 Thanks, I was needing Contains but couldn't remember the syntax

Comment: Thanks alot! Toootally forgot about those several comparison operators!

Answer (score 1):

A quick read on jQuery selectors should do the trick (as mentioned by Rionmonster above). I'd just like to note that you can also check for elements with a specific attribute (which I expect you'll actually need?) by doing something like

```
$('a[href]')
```

This finds `<a>` elements that have a defined `href` attribute, whether that be a hash or anything else. Good for filtering out clickable anchors.

Answer (score -1):

Read about JQuery selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/