# Is this the most efficient way to add active class to navbar with bootstrap 4

Tags: class, bootstrap-4, navigation

Here's the short little js script I'm using:

```
var locations = ['index', 'about', 'blog', 'contact', 'services']
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav li');
var wlp = window.location.pathname;

locations.forEach((page) => {
   if (wlp.includes(page)) {
       for (let i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
            if (navLinks[i].classList.contains("active")) {
                navLinks[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            let href = navLinks[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
            if (href.includes(page)) navLinks[i].classList.add("active");
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You don’t need to check if a <li> has the active class — just remove it (if the class isn’t present, [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) doesn’t [error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove)). You could just leave `active` out from the source file and not need to remove it. Usually, the active page is set at the server via PHP, etc. Even with just static pages, usually the active page is preset into each static file. You should be removing and adding `<span class="sr-only">(current)` to the anchor HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav li.active');
```

So, you did'nt need to test it

But even smarter here is to use JQuery (you load it already because of bs4)

```
locations.forEach((page) => { 
  if (wlp.includes(page)) {
     $('nav li')
      .removeClass('active')
      .children().filter(('a[href="'+page+'"]')).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

See
[jQuery filter :contains for a link (a href="#")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653920/jquery-filter-contains-for-a-link-a-href)
https://api.jquery.com/filter/
https://api.jquery.com/children/#children-selector

Easier to understand:

```
locations.forEach((page) => { 
  if (wlp.includes(page)) {
     $('nav li.active').removeClass('active'):
     $('nav li a[href="'+page+'"]')).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: shouldn't  $('nav li.active a[href="'+page+'"]')).addClass('active'); be  $('nav li a[href="'+page+'"]')).addClass('active');  ???